# Wordpress . How to move some post from front page to a different page?

Tags: wordpress, post, move

I have 40 or so post on a WordPress site.

I need to move about 20 of them to a new page I created.

I have created to (New) page and a new category for these post.

I changed edit some of the post and changed the category to the new one.

They show up on the (New) page , but they all so show up on the Front page as well.

What needs to be done to get the post to just show up on the (New) page and not the Main page of the site.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exclude that category from the front page like so:

```
if ( is_front_page() ) { query_posts( 'cat=-1' ); }
```

Switch out the "1" with the ID of the category you want to exclude. The - sign in front of the ID says it is excluded.

Reference: [WordPress Codex: Query Posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)